# How do you convert a hexadecimal string into a number in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, operators, pipeline, aggregation

I have a collection that has strings such as this:

```
left_eye_val : "0x0", right_eye_val : "0x2"
```

I'm setting up some derivative fields as part of a aggregation pipeline which at its first stage must convert the hexadecimal strings "0x0", "0x2" into numbers.

The operator I tried:
`{$toInt:"$left_eye_val"}` returns `Illegal hexadecimal input in $convert with onError value:0x0`

Is there a way to convert these strings into numbers using built-in mongodb operators?  If not, what are some of the ways one might accomplish this?

Comment: Why put these values into the database as strings to begin with?

Comment: the upstream application left all data as strings without regard for data-type.

Comment: seems like the only alternative would be to create a custom function https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/ please confirm

Comment: the question continues https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67442501/how-do-you-refer-to-a-field-for-an-input-parameter-to-function-in-mongodb/67444055?noredirect=1#comment119291695_67444055 on an attempt for an alternative solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Domscheit's answer works if the hexadecimal string does not contain the '0x' in front of it; if it does, then modify the function posted by @Domscheit as follows:

```
function baseToDecimal(input, base) {
   // works up to 72057594037927928 / FFFFFFFFFFFFF8
   var field = input;
   return {
      $sum: {
         $map: {
            input: { $range: [0, { $strLenBytes: field }] },
            in: {
               $multiply: [
                  { $pow: [base, { $subtract: [{ $strLenBytes: field }, { $add: ["$$this", 1] }] }] },
                  { $indexOfBytes: ["0123456789ABCDEF", { $toUpper: { $substrBytes: [field, "$$this", 1] } }] }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   };
}
```

and call it as follows, using the `replaceOne` function to remove the `x`

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$set:{lHex: {$replaceOne: {input:"$hex", find:"x", replacement: "0"}}}}, {$set: {decimal: baseToDecimal("$lHex", 16)}}])
```

Answer (score 2):

Such function does not exist yet, see [Support base conversion in $convert](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-35013)

You can define functions like this:

```
function decimalToBase(input, base) {
   // works up to 72057594037927928 / FFFFFFFFFFFFF8
   var field = "$" + input;
   return {
      $let: {
         vars: {
            bits: {
               $reduce: {
                  input: { $range: [0, 56] },
                  initialValue: [{ dec: field }],
                  in: {
                     $cond: {
                        if: { $gt: [{ $last: "$$value.dec" }, 0] },
                        then: {
                           $concatArrays: ["$$value",
                              [{
                                 b: { $substrBytes: ["0123456789ABCDEF", { $mod: [{ $last: "$$value.dec" }, base] }, 1] },
                                 dec: { $trunc: { $divide: [{ $last: "$$value.dec" }, base] } }
                              }]
                           ]
                        },
                        else: "$$value"
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         },
         in: {
            $reduce: {
               input: { $reverseArray: "$$bits.b" },
               initialValue: "",
               in: { $concat: ["$$value", "$$this"] }
            }
         }
      }
   }
};

function baseToDecimal(input, base) {
   // works up to 72057594037927928 / FFFFFFFFFFFFF8
   var field = "$" + input;
   return {
      $sum: {
         $map: {
            input: { $range: [0, { $strLenBytes: field }] },
            in: {
               $multiply: [
                  { $pow: [base, { $subtract: [{ $strLenBytes: field }, { $add: ["$$this", 1] }] }] },
                  { $indexOfBytes: ["0123456789ABCDEF", { $toUpper: { $substrBytes: [field, "$$this", 1] } }] }
               ]
            }
         }
      }
   };
}
```

and then use it, for example like this:

```
db.collection.insertOne({ hex: "A3F" })
db.collection.aggregate({ $set: { decimal: baseToDecimal("hex", 16)} })
```