# how do you refer to a field for an input parameter to function in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, function, aggregation

This is a continuation of the question I asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67426169/how-do-you-convert-a-hexadecimal-string-into-a-number-in-mongodb)

I'm trying to simplify the suggested solution by using the following function instead:

```
function hexStringToInt(hexString) {return(parseInt(hexString, 16));}
```

here is a series of examples of its usage on a small example collection:

when I provide the function with hardcoded "0x02", it works correctly to convert it to an integer (2) (see the rxRight field)

```
> db.collection.aggregate([{$addFields:{rxLeft:"0x0"}}, {$addFields:{rxRight: hexStringToInt("0x2")}}])
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "apple", "totalPrice" : NumberDecimal("50.0000000000000"), "rxLeft" : "0x0", "rxRight" : 2 }
```

however, when i try to assign the new-field rxRight with the *value* of the new-field rxLeft as input into the function, it returns a NaN.

```
> db.collection.aggregate([{$addFields:{rxLeft:"0x0"}}, {$addFields:{rxRight: hexStringToInt("$rxLeft")}}])
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "apple", "totalPrice" : NumberDecimal("50.0000000000000"), "rxLeft" : "0x0", "rxRight" : NaN }
```

What is the correct way to pass a new-field as in input to a function?

Based on @Joe's input, i tried using `baseToDecimal` and it is unable to resolve `rxleft`:

Removing the `$` sign as Joe suggested resolves, but as `-14` instead of `2`

```
> db.collection.aggregate([{$addFields:{rxLeft:"0x2"}}, {$addFields:{rxRight: baseToDecimal("rxLeft", 16)}}])
{ "_id" : 1, "item" : "apple", "totalPrice" : NumberDecimal("50.0000000000000"), "rxLeft" : "0x2", "rxRight" : -14 }
```

here is the execution result from the shell as requested:

```
> baseToDecimal("rxRight",16)
{"$sum": {
     "$map": {
        "input" : {"$range": [0,{"$strLenBytes": "$rxRight"}]},
        "in" : {"$multiply": [
                    {"$pow": [16,{"$subtract" : [
                                       {"$strLenBytes": "$rxRight"},
                                       {"$add": ["$$this",1]}
                    ]}]},
                    {"$indexOfBytes" : [
                            "0123456789ABCDEF",
                            {"$toUpper": {
                                "$substrBytes" : [
                                   "$rxRight",
                                   "$$this",
                                   1
                                ]
                            }}
                    ]}
        ]}
     }
}}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `hexStringToInt` function is evaluated in the client, and its value passed to the server in the aggregate call.

The javascript code for that function is not sent to the server.  The string literal "$rsleft" is passed to parseInt, which returns `NaN`, so the pipeline stage passed to the server is `{$addFields:{rxRight: NaN}}`

The decimalToBase function in the answer to your other question is a function that returns an object containing aggregation operators.

That function is also evaluated on the client side, and its returned object is passed as part of the aggregation pipeline, and executed server side.

Try running `baseToDecimal("hex",16)` to see the return value.

Comment: edited to add in @Joe's input to use baseToDecimal shows it is unable to resolve the value of rxleft

Comment: Don't add the `$` to the field name when calling baseToDecimal

Comment: Run `baseToDecimal("rxRight",16)` in the shell so you can see the generated code.

Comment: I edited my original question to add in you request for generated code hopefully i followed correctly what you were asking

Comment: Exactly.  So the question now is do you understand what that code does when you send it inside of an `$addFields` stage? Note that the function itself is never sent to the server, it is that output that is sent.

Comment: So are we saying that what I'm trying to do is not possible without a server-side function built into the mongodb framework?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232251/discussion-between-sblu-and-joe).

Comment: issue is that the 0x is not handled by the original solution; the 'x' must be removed.  please see the updated solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67541245/14656464