# hash 64 bits in mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, hash

Does MongoDB provide a native function for generating 64-bit hashes of strings to anonymize data? This functionality is necessary for an aggregation pipeline I'm developing.

Comment: 64 bits would give you a non-negligible danger of collision. You could just take the first 16 hex digits of any hash.

Comment: None that I am aware of. In the official documentation of [$function](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/function/#example-1--usage-example), there is a canonical use case of computing md5 sum using javascript. I guess you might also need to resort to javascript with `$function` too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `$toHashedIndexKey()` function appears to generate ~64 bit numbers, as `Long`'s.

And if you want to convert that to hex, you will need to use a `$function` or [implement it in JS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67429422/1431750).

From the [docs of $toHashedIndexKey](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toHashedIndexKey/):

> You can use `$toHashedIndexKey` to compute the hashed value of a string in an aggregation pipeline. This example computes the hashed value of the string `"string to hash"`:
>
> ```js
> db.aggregate(
>   [
>      { $documents: [ { val: "string to hash" } ] },
>      { $addFields: { hashedVal: { $toHashedIndexKey: "$val" } } }
>   ]
> )
> ```
>
> Example output:
>
> ```
> [ { val: 'string to hash', hashedVal: Long("763543691661428748") } ]
> ```

Example usage:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $set: {
      name: { $toHashedIndexKey: "$name" }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T2wDf3M152B)